# data of class numeric error when plotting vertical and horizontal lines in ggplot

Tags: r, shiny

```
iarray <- iv$iarray
varray <- iv$varray
n<-gsub("^\\{+(.+)\\}+$", '\\1', iarray)
n1 <- strsplit(n,",")
n1 <- unlist(n1)
n1 <- as.numeric(n1)
df <- as.data.frame(n1)
n<-gsub("^\\{+(.+)\\}+$", '\\1', varray)
n2 <- strsplit(n,",")
n2 <- unlist(n2)
n2 <- as.numeric(n2)
df <- cbind(df,n2)
vmpp <-iv$vmpp
impp <- iv$impp
print(impp)
print(vmpp)
     })

     output$ivcurve <- renderPlot({

       ggplot(data3(), aes(x=n2, y= n1)) + geom_line(colour='blue')+ geom_vline(xintercept = vmpp)+ geom_hline(yintercept =  impp) +  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 11))
```

Basically I'm trying to draw an IV curve from the above code. 
[image]

As seen in the photo I need a horizontal and a vertical line.

But after I added the geom_vline function it gives me the `Error : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric`

iv is a dataframe and iarray and varray basically looks like this.

```
iarray = "{9.467182035,9.252423958,9.179368178,9.142931845}"
varray = "{-1.025945126,-0.791203874,-0.506481774,-0.255416444}"
```

And `vmpp` and `impp` are basically numbers as `8.5` and `20`

suggestions?

```
  P.s : 


dput(iv)
structure(list(id = 3L, seris_id = "SERTPTR0003", module_id = 2L, 
    isc = 9.1043, voc = 37.61426, impp = 8.524, vmpp = 30.0118, 
    pmpp = 255.8095, unique_halm_id = 4414L, iarray = "{9.471385758,9.251831868,9.174032904,9.135095327,9.109244512,9.087563112,9.081257993,9.079282455,9.078209387,9.077396672,9.076717653,9.076285598,9.075914058,9.075549594,9.075098675,9.074659768,9.074080201,9.073659578,9.073411255,9.073349331,9.073215686,9.073189667,9.073011759,9.072868405,9.072659064,9.072636165,9.072659725,9.072729724,9.072779321,9.072915415,9.072951718,9.072855259,9.072758863,9.072562734,9.072286497,9.072036161,9.071858009,9.07165223,9.071458902,9.071172024,9.070818323,9.070364851,9.069865071,9.069392026,9.069058847,9.068673155,9.068486996,9.0684006,9.068241175,9.067848351,9.067533806,9.066886103,9.066177782,9.0655086,9.065025577,9.064457111,9.064154995,9.063866251,9.063564149,9.063221961,9.06295813,9.062580288,9.062182005,9.06179715,9.061378517,9.060847632,9.06033015,9.059686156,9.058814993,9.057817299,9.056732355,9.055534236,9.054389596,9.05351149,9.052819766,9.052254696,9.051816304,9.051431465,9.051000987,9.050664797,9.050589584,9.050615635,9.050795719,9.051096084,9.05121704,9.050958132,9.050478383,9.049724325,9.048695951,9.047619756,9.046715916,9.04602525,9.045615278,9.045512729,9.045617691,9.045803509,9.045989974,9.046083526,9.045997615,9.045871618,9.045772357,9.045599926,9.045340971,9.045082036,9.04473025,9.044178732,9.043440888,9.042642632,9.04185002,9.041056695,9.040316091,9.039781509,9.039426971,9.039199774,9.039026035,9.038805897,9.038478843,9.037978051,9.037190302,9.036262611,9.035408047,9.034687132,9.03411323,9.033759457,9.033445779,9.033105372,9.032611665,9.031991392,9.031298017,9.030631384,9.029991493,9.02931152,9.028518372,9.027678053,9.026644378,9.025384369,9.023971135,9.022443918,9.020510444,9.018469233,9.015987042,9.013123551,9.009951782,9.006524239,9.002508657,8.99806541,8.993200713,8.987509287,8.980851319,8.97337198,8.964883202,8.955065215,8.944015742,8.931773812,8.91796823,8.902911552,8.886450605,8.868452754,8.848678419,8.827119435,8.80336248,8.777313996,8.748941051,8.718309497,8.685225063,8.649388501,8.610785476,8.569040812,8.52363426,8.474699468,8.422382481,8.366516735,8.307103187,8.244481209,8.178090447,8.10779633,8.033345875,7.954744415,7.871665908,7.784296593,7.692116999,7.595199333,7.493377787,7.386704971,7.275055109,7.158981607,7.038484468,6.913650942,6.784728642,6.651977027,6.515069048,6.374111623,6.228897233,6.079031999,5.924669253,5.766323899,5.604063459,5.43841477,5.26939121,5.096619936,4.919752772,4.738936722,4.554312451,4.366039658,4.174017769,3.978461295,3.779470133,3.576724216,3.370764477,3.162238756,2.951119622,2.737359938,2.521133452,2.302407806,2.08132299,1.858467726,1.632539296,1.397202225,1.149523324,0.890812319,0.62251893,0.349040094,0.084409259,-0.164612445,-0.4001423,-0.625408177,-0.844927296,-1.067373925,-1.297998987,-1.536777099,-1.782558235,-2.033692207,-2.28906274,-2.54694712,-2.806836154,-3.068463186,-3.331653821,-3.596227332,-3.862303417,-4.129421924,-4.397321356,-4.666082505,-4.935632162,-5.206170796,-5.478105728,-5.751638617,-6.027203502,-6.304753878,-6.584235675,-6.865027697,-7.146774939,-7.428922534,-7.711971427,-7.995982555,-8.281623641,-8.569128828,-8.85847189,-9.14887768,-9.440152159,-9.731968139,-10.02382391,-10.315645796,-10.608918155,-10.906228043,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}", 
    varray = "{-1.055634971,-0.820094649,-0.530478984,-0.277519378,-0.049665975,0.168173928,0.369832037,0.557189853,0.73806136,0.918444007,1.100988955,1.285835111,1.471379381,1.656087228,1.83947039,2.021804885,2.204138782,2.387586314,2.572217234,2.757544476,2.943083961,3.127927125,3.311936258,3.49497066,3.677517995,3.860273388,4.043516446,4.227247167,4.411953813,4.597148124,4.781785019,4.965795342,5.149247651,5.331933288,5.514618924,5.698279889,5.882706331,6.067759345,6.253369179,6.43883951,6.623542572,6.807967224,6.991834459,7.175283184,7.359219574,7.543715171,7.727930567,7.91102934,8.092315166,8.270881273,8.44728269,8.622987785,8.800575578,8.981370755,9.16634984,9.355446065,9.546982405,9.738937256,9.930334092,10.119987137,10.30698723,10.492242934,10.676242509,10.859335313,11.042009008,11.224684494,11.40735998,11.589966311,11.77250289,11.955040067,12.138134659,12.321927365,12.506347836,12.691464628,12.877626501,13.06357852,13.248553416,13.432761044,13.616063692,13.798391012,13.981067688,14.165071441,14.350401073,14.536497974,14.722526917,14.907441627,15.090542195,15.272247132,15.453463208,15.634886746,15.817842429,16.00302897,16.188982779,16.375285347,16.561309505,16.745870074,16.92840904,17.110739948,17.293002899,17.47610287,17.660388619,17.84523298,18.029659429,18.213737119,18.397257992,18.580849811,18.765279846,18.950546303,19.136368979,19.322329963,19.507382979,19.691527431,19.874834264,20.057444179,20.239565832,20.422106592,20.605414621,20.789699174,20.974891096,21.161129891,21.347647095,21.533745789,21.718937711,21.903640773,22.087576567,22.271163603,22.454611733,22.638548722,22.822346805,23.006144888,23.189873219,23.373392294,23.556911967,23.740989056,23.925624756,24.110540657,24.296084919,24.481558832,24.666267268,24.850416495,25.034286715,25.217528572,25.400211222,25.582891485,25.765153238,25.947554494,26.130303912,26.31319522,26.495810505,26.678077627,26.859158373,27.03919344,27.2183891,27.396813913,27.574889968,27.752475972,27.92950277,28.106320312,28.283627309,28.460794206,28.638101203,28.814990286,28.99097379,29.16472524,29.336732302,29.506996765,29.675866194,29.843757906,30.011789121,30.179820337,30.347501601,30.514694006,30.680631478,30.844614709,31.006505389,31.166790586,31.32526224,31.482546323,31.638644628,31.793695462,31.947491958,32.10059034,32.252713392,32.40427843,32.555147743,32.705110284,32.853817294,33.001129867,33.14656034,33.29010692,33.431979459,33.572526716,33.711957348,33.85055096,33.988306953,34.125295678,34.260890565,34.395089819,34.528311952,34.660559355,34.792040088,34.923102908,35.053748414,35.1835569,35.312946278,35.441359731,35.568936163,35.695816274,35.821859963,35.946717873,36.071016573,36.194685715,36.317446291,36.439648854,36.561153301,36.681402816,36.801235017,36.924136292,37.050595501,37.180333637,37.313071096,37.446575824,37.573873847,37.693009727,37.80489203,37.910636184,38.012195237,38.11396235,38.218102215,38.324333435,38.432308447,38.541817399,38.652023867,38.762158191,38.872501769,38.982844151,39.092768022,39.202552988,39.31199099,39.420452469,39.528287977,39.635566071,39.742146647,39.848308713,39.954401627,40.060004483,40.165396887,40.270857247,40.376317008,40.481775571,40.587234732,40.692485836,40.797320225,40.901805855,41.005874173,41.109873339,41.21366265,41.317242107,41.420542558,41.523772657,41.626762446,41.729471102,41.832232456,41.937530675,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}"), .Names = c("id", 
"seris_id", "module_id", "isc", "voc", "impp", "vmpp", "pmpp", 
"unique_halm_id", "iarray", "varray"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you sure `iv$impp` is a number? Check with `typeof` if it is double or character. You can try to cast it to numeric like `impp <- as.numeric(iv$impp)`. Otherwise we need a `dput(iv)` to have a reproducible example.

Comment: @drmariod I have added `dput(iv)` for the post for reference.

Comment: Have you tried a reproducible example outside of shiny? What is the result of `data3()`?

Comment: @drmariod it works fine outside shiny. 
`data3()` gives a reactive output. So my iv data.frame always keeps changing.

Comment: How are you building data3? Have you checked that the inputs you use to shape data3 have valid values and that data3 is a data.frame with values in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. since the ggplot requires data frames. I just added two more columns to the data frame and added them there.

```
vmpp <- iv$vmpp
df <- cbind(df,vmpp)
impp <- iv$impp
df <- cbind(df,impp)
print(df)

     })

     output$ivcurve <- renderPlot({

      ggplot(data3(), aes(x=n2, y= n1)) + geom_line(colour='blue')+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 11))+ geom_vline(aes(xintercept = vmpp))+  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = impp))
```